# How can i get possible attr_accesible attributes in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessible

Since it is possible to define attr_accesible with a role `attr_accessible :name, :as => :admin` how can i get all attr_accesible attributes in a view for a specific role?

With this information it would be possible to show a custom view form.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model's name is `Foo`, use [`accessible_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accessible_attributes):

```
Foo.accessible_attributes(:admin).to_a
```

Comment: @tonymarschall I was originally following [how they get set](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a1b9acb72ec4b3a3d11f77efe64effb79e58b45d/activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb#L172), and using that as a basis for how to access them, but there's actually a documented method that does this too sans the underscore prefix. I've updated my question with that and a link to the docs. (Since it's documented, yes, it is "official" `:)`)